# GIT refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object

Tags: git

Here's my problem:

1. I create a new git repository named 'project'. It has some files in it.
2. I clone that repository with:

   `git clone --bare project project.git`
3. Git tells me:
   `Cloning into bare repository 'project.git'...
   done. error: refs/head/master does not point to a valid object!`
4. I do get a directory named project.git but if I go on with:

   - `git init --bare --shared project.git`
   - `git clone project.git project2`
5. Git tells me:

   `Cloning into 'project2'...
   warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
   done.`

So I now have no files in the cloned repository: 'project2'. I first encountered this problem with an existing repository that I was trying to share by a bare clone as I usually do. Now it happens with all new repositories that I create. However, If I create the reposotory then copy it to my other machine and then make the bare clone on it, I have no problems.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Update:

The probelm is only occurin on a network drive not the local disk. C is my local disk and H is my network disk:

### Local = no problems:

```
$ cd c:/temp
$ mkdir foo; cd foo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/temp/foo/.git/
$ echo 'a' > a; git add a; git commit -m 'a'
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in a.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
[master (root-commit) f695c9d] a
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in a.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a
$ cd ..
$ git clone --bare foo foo.git
Cloning into bare repository 'foo.git'...
done.
$ ls foo.git/
HEAD  config  description  hooks  info  objects  packed-refs  refs
```

### Network disk = problems:

```
$ cd h:
$ mkdir foo; cd foo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in h:/foo/.git/
$ echo 'a' > a; git add a; git commit -m 'a'
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in a.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
[master (root-commit) 5348b42] a
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in a.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a
$ cd ..
$ git clone --bare foo foo.git
Cloning into bare repository 'foo.git'...
done.
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
$ ls foo.git/
HEAD  config  description  hooks  info  objects  packed-refs  refs
```

Comment: It's unclear: does in the original repo refs/head/master point to a valid commit or not? Is that a perfectly working repo that only misbehaves on cloning? does it have a master branch at all?

Comment: The original repo points to a valid commit. ie the SHA1 code matches between a commit and the refs/heads/master. I'm not sure how to tell if this is a valid commit otherwise. The repo only appears to misbehave on cloning; I can copy it to another machine and clone it there and have no problems. Not sure what you mean by: 'does it have a master branch at all?' The repo only has a master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Does this differ from your result:

```
$ mkdir foo; cd foo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/foo/.git/
$ echo 'a' > a; git add a; git commit -m 'a'
[master (root-commit) 235e657] a
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a
$ cd ..
$ git clone --bare foo foo.git
Cloning into bare repository 'foo.git'...
done.
$ ls foo.git/
HEAD        config      hooks/      objects/    refs/
branches/   description info/       packed-refs
```

if so, I'd suggest something is wrong with your 'project' repository.  For example, if you never committed in 'project' then this occurs:

```
$ mkdir bar; cd bar; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/bar/.git/
$ echo 'a' > a; git add a
$ cd ..
$ git clone --bare bar bar.git
Cloning into bare repository 'bar.git'...
done.
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Comment: yeah, I'd suspect that too, and probably run fsck and/or fetch over the content to a fresh one.

Comment: I added an update. It seems that I can only recreate the issue on the network disk. The repo that was causing me the initial trouble is in fact on the network disk. I copied it off the network disk and have no problems with it. As you can see in the output I added to the initial message; a fresh repo with a single text file creates the same error on the network disc but not the local disc.

Answer (score -1):

the answer is really easy, I had the same problem. GIT does not allow google drive to update \refs\heads\master , so you end up with two different references codes on the machine A which you have made a commit & push and on another machine B which you are trying to clone it to... change manually reference code on your machine B and it works perfectly, but, anyway it is pointless yo update master file every time manually after every single commit :)