# GIT - Commit available in git repo but not showing in local repo

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, npm-install

I am having a issue in NPM install now. I am having a value in package.json like this

```
"angular-dynamic-locale": "git://github.com/xxxx/angular-dynamic-locale"
```

and similarly some other values are also like this in the file.

After doing NPM install I am getting an error like this

```
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 2bebf3223b7b9ab00a18e294a52bcfffbbe066b7: fatal: bad object 2bebf3223b7b9ab00a18e294a52bcfffbbe066b7
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 2bebf3223b7b9ab00a18e294a52bcfffbbe066b7:
```

For all the other similar values which have private github repos in Package.json I am getting this same error with its corresponding commit head

I searched in corresponding git hub repo. But there I found a value with this github commit ID 2bebf3223b7b9ab00a18e294a52bcfffbbe066b7

Is there any idea what the problem is. Or what is the possible solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728665/how-to-use-private-github-repo-as-npm-dependency

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani: I already had my ssh setup, but gave the value like this git+ssh://git@github.com/xxxx/angular-dynamic-locale.git. Still the same error exists

Comment: Does `git+ssh://git@github.com/xxxx/angular-dynamic-locale.git#master` changes the result?

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani :No, Still shows the same issue

Comment: Can you clone the repo?

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani: Yeah I can clone the repo.

Comment: So I don't know. Maybe these are useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797315/fatal-bad-object-head  and http://slopjong.de/2014/06/11/git-bad-object-head/