# How can I recover from 'fatal: reference is not a tree: master'?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a git folder, which has two branches, `master` and `working`.

for reasons I cant explain, when I run a `git branch`command, I get three branches:

- `desktop.ini`
- `master`
- `working`

The `working` branch is up to date (after a reset), and has what I want in it.

The `desktop.ini` branch is not supposed to exist. When I run

```
git branch -d desktop.ini
```

it says that it doesn't exist and can't be deleted. It also can't be checkout out. There is a `desktop.ini` file in each folder in the Git repo, as it is a Google Drive folder in which the repo is stored.

The main problem, however, is that I can no longer access the `master` branch. Every time I try

```
git checkout master
```

I get back

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: master.
```

If I try deleting it, I get

```
error: couldn't look up commit object for refs/heads/master
```

Having checked manually this file does exist in the correct directory, and has a head inside it.

I also tried creating a new `master` branch, but was told a branch named "master" already exists. Finally, running `git log` gave the most recent commit, and then

```
error: could not read c7d68...blah blah
fatal: failed to traverse parents of commit aed8af.....
```

Is there any easy way of resuscitating the `master` branch?

UPDATE: copied the head from the working branch to the master branch, i now have access again to master. However every `git status`returns

```
error: could not read c7d68.....
error: could not read c7d68.....
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit aed8......
```

Do I need to act to correct this?

Comment: Have you tried `git fetch --unshallow`?

Comment: what does `git show-branch` show?

Comment: @BobMazanec `git show-branch`results in "error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object". Could google driving syncing things be the issue? if so, to corrct the issue, can i copy thhe contents of the working branch head into master head?

@pyerwin: what does tha command do? I'm far form an expert at git, and google didn't turn much up

Comment: @Mauvai, network drive might be at least part of the problem -- cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274575/git-refs-heads-master-does-not-point-to-a-valid-object

Comment: @BobMazanec Added an update

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem myself this morning.

In my case I'm running an **Ubuntu VM on a Windows host**.  The Ubuntu VM is used for development, but the files I'm working with are actually in a directory shared from the host OS.

Windows wont allow adding `desktop.ini` files to all the directories in the shared directory... including the `.git` directory and all of its subdirectories. Git is seeing these files in places where it's not expecting a third party to be manipulating the contents; so when I execute `git branch` I get a listing very similar to that of the questioner.

The key here is that these obviously aren't real branches.  They're just files in places where Git is expecting to be able to do a simple enumeration of directory contents in order to find what branches exist.  When you try to do something more substantial, like delete this new `desktop.ini` branch, it fails because it's not a real branch.

I resolved this very simply by deleting all the `desktop.ini` files that were added to the `.git` directory structure by Windows.

As soon as I did that, the phantom branches went away and everything worked fine (it was screwing up git-flow in my case since git-flow saw file in `.git/refs/release` as a current release in progress branch).  I do expect these to come back if I continue to host these files in the Windows host file system.

There may be a more permanent way to prevent this, but I haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: I cant check this out as those files are long, long gone, but thanks for the answer - I'll keep it in mind!